# where is the contacts.json file for ember examples

Tags: ember.js

I've downloaded the samples for ember.js and followed the directions to start the contact example via node and localhost:3000  But, there's no contacts.json file that I can find so nothing loads.  Clicking New Contact does nothing.  I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot this but I'm wondering if it has to do with no contacts.json file being present when according to the description there should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Ember examples appear to be a little out-of-date at the moment (the contacts demo still references the SC namespace last I checked) and some may be broken. I suspect that once Ember 1.0 is released this will get cleaned up. You can [view issues for emberjs/examples on github](https://github.com/emberjs/examples/issues?state=open).

I don't think your problem is because of the missing contacts.json file because it's broken on the live [contacts demo](http://emberjs.com/examples/contacts/) too--console shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

You can comment-out the parts of the contacts example that load the JSON data to make that error go away, e.g.,

```
//App.contactsController.loadContacts();
```

or you could create a new JSON file, e.g.,

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Alice",
        "lastName": "Anderson",
        "phoneNumbers": [
            "+1 123-456-7890"
        ]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "José",
        "lastName": "Zulu",
        "phoneNumbers": [
            "+55 (11) 5000-6000"
        ]
    }
]
```

However, it might be better not to base your education on the examples right now. Check out the reference documentation and some of the good articles for getting started instead. I found [trek's article: Advice on & Instruction in the Use Of Ember.js](http://trek.github.com/) to be helpful.

Comment: You might also be seeing errors from node.js related to package.json, which is different. http://package.json.jit.su/